# Struggling with Conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, conditional-statements

It's my first post here and I am fairly new to SQL. I am having a hard time returning the correct field counts. I am supposed to return 3 rows: Stores=701, Persons=18484, StoreWithContact=635. StoreWithContact=635 is returned when Both the PersonID and StoreID are not null. I have tried adding an additional conditional statement like this:

```
Select Count (StoreID ) as 'Stores', Count(PersonID) as 'Persons'
From Sales.Customer 
Where PersonID is Null or StoreID is Null or (PersonID is not null AND StoreID is not null)
```

But when I do that the count number for Stores and Persons changes because it follows the additional conditional statement I added.

I am new to SQL and I am trying to figure this out but I am lost! Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[Visual to what I am describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twnnf.png)

Comment: If both are integers; `count(StoreID + PersonID)`.

Comment: Side note: `COUNT(SomeNonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional sum like this

```
SELECT count(StoreID) AS Stores, 
       count(PersonID) AS Persons,
       sum(CASE WHEN PersonID IS NOT NULL AND StoreID IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS StoresWithContacts
FROM Sales.Customer
```